# BeautifulSoup - str(soup) is not same as html given

Tags: python, html, string, beautifulsoup

```py
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> html = """<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<p><b>para1</b><\p>
<p><b>para2</b><\p>
</body>
</html>"""
>>> 
>>> soup = bs(html)
>>> html == str(soup)
False
>>> print html
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<p><b>para1</b><\p>
<p><b>para2</b><\p>
</body>
</html>
>>> print soup
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<p><b>para1</b>&lt;\p&gt;
<p><b>para2</b>&lt;\p&gt;
</p></p></body>
</html>
```

As you can see there is a difference between `html` and `str(soup)`..

```
< became &lt;
> became &gt;
```

Why is this happening??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have invalid HTML, and BeautifulSoup tried to fix that as best it could.

Note the `<\p>` tags are escaped, because they are not valid HTML closing tags. Instead, proper `</p>` tags have been added.

Answer (score 2):

The closing tags for your `<p>` element have the slashes the wrong way around. As this is soup and not XML, bs4 accepts this, but rightfully escapes this if your print it.